# MJML mj-image fill height of container

Tags: image, email, mjml

I'm building an email template with MJML

This is the requested layout.

[image: Requested layout]

This is what I have now.

[image: Actual layout]

I need the image to fill the height of the container so that it has the same height as the other column with the text.

This is the code I'm working with.

```
<mj-section padding="0" background-color="#856555" direction="rtl">
<mj-column>
    <mj-image
        src="https://example.com/image.jpg"
        padding="0"
        fluid-on-mobile="true"
    />
</mj-column>
<mj-column padding="20px">
    <mj-raw>
        <span style="color: #fff; opacity: .5; float: left; margin-right: 16px">OUR</span>
        <span style="color: #fff; opacity: .5; float: right;">ATHLETES</span>
    </mj-raw>

    <mj-text color="#fff" padding="40px 0 32px" font-size="36px" line-height="1.3"> 101 <br> LOREM IPSUM </mj-text>
    <mj-text color="#fff" padding="0 0 16px" font-size="14px" line-height="1.4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor[...]
    </mj-text>
    <mj-button mj-class="btn-white" align="left"> SCOPRI </mj-button>
</mj-column>
```

I'm using fluid-on-mobile="true" to fill the container in the mobile view of the email but I need it to fill the height as well in the desktop view. Does anyone have an idea of how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible as images sadly don't get the same properties they can on web, like `object-fit: cover;` (which would be great). Percentage based size is also out of the question.

You have 2 solutions, both with downsides:

[image]

**1. Set a fixed height for the image**
If you know the amount of content you'll have on the side, you can take this route. Yes, it stretches the images and deforms it, but gets the job done. If the stretching is not too much, maybe it can go unnoticed. The image only gets the fixed height treatment on desktop. On mobile, it keeps the "auto" sizing.

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/DJcPAc-sH

---

[image]

**2. Center-align the content**

Not as great in my opinion, as it diverts too much from the design and breaks the layout, but it keeps the content aligned and is probably ideal if you have no control over the content (or its length) on the left.

https://mjml.io/try-it-live/Pwi5wopxy

Comment: I forgot to update the question myself but I figured that these were the only two options and endend up going with the second one as I have no control over the text content on the left. I gave a heads up to the client and they were fine with it. In the end I think it's the better solution since it avoids the image stretching and can match the layout with a little care on the text content part.